# only returning records when s.id = u.summary_id

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select
 s.id, s.description, s.improvement, s.previous_year_id, 
 s.current_year_id, s.first_name,  s.last_name, s.username, 
 s.finding, s.action, s.share, s.learned, s.timestamp, 
 d.title as department_title, 
 group_concat(g.title SEPARATOR \' | \') as strategic_goals,
 y1.year as current_year_title, y2.year as previous_year_title,
 u.summary_id, u.file_name as file_name
from
 summary s, year y1, year y2, strategic_goal_entries sge, 
 goal g, department d, uploads u
where
 s.id = sge.summary_id
and
 s.current_year_id = y1.id
and
 s.previous_year_id = y2.id
and
 sge.goal_id = g.id
and
 s.id = u.summary_id
and
 s.department_id = d.id
and
 s.department_id = '4'
group by
 s.id
```

This only returns records from the summary table that has a relating record in the uploads table (s.id = uploads.summary_id) that contain a value within the uploads.summary_id field

I want to return all records, whether or not it has a file associated with it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Left join with uploads table ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest refactoring this SQL query to use ANSI joins. To achive your goal, you'd want a LEFT JOIN instead:

```
SELECT /*your columns*/
from    summary s 
INNER JOIN year y1 ON  s.current_year_id = y1.id
INNER JOIN  year y2 ON  s.previous_year_id = y2.id
INNER JOIN  strategic_goal_entries sge  ON   s.id = sge.summary_id
INNER JOIN goal g ON  sge.goal_id = g.id
INNER JOIN  department d  ON  s.department_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN  uploads u ON  s.id = u.summary_id 

WHERE  s.department_id = '4'
group by  s.id
```